# How to access multiple values to code igniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Passing multiple values as an array is working. But when i want access the variable only 1st array variable can access. 
I think the problem comes from model. when i used `$this->db->select('*');` no issue occur. Why it happen? Then how to access other variable.

Controller

```
public function index() {                    
    $this->load->model('prop_model');         
    $pro_data['pro'] = $this->prop_model->get_data_all();
    $this->load->view('home/main_view', $pro_data);    
}
```

Model (prop_model)

```
function get_data_all() { 
    $this->db->select('prop_id', 'content', 'added_date'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('tble_prol');        
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

view

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <?php
        foreach ($pro as $add) {
          echo '<div class="grid-item well"><p>'
          . $add->content .'<br>' . $add->added_date //error here when access added_date
            . '</p></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: check the result of `$pro`

Comment: `print_r($pro)` in views and post its value!!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @saty When print_r($pro). It displays only `prop_id` values. Is there any wrong in my `SQL`?

Comment: When i put ` $this->db->select('*'); ` its working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('prop_id,content,added_date');
```

The query syntax is wrong. See for the reference: [ActiveRecordsSyntax](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)